# Unable to update packages?

Tags: 11.10, flash, updates

When I was updating Ubuntu, it got stuck when updating Adobe Flash so I turned the computer off. Now when I try to update it doesn't work. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a terminal window, please run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That should fix the broken packages.

You can open the Terminal with the ctrl+alt+t key combination.

Comment: Glad I could help.